# Require directive in .htaccess prevents directories from being shown

Tags: apache, .htaccess, apache2, webserver, authorization

I have the following directory hierarchy

```
-root_folder
   .htaccess
   -sub_folder
       .htaccess
```

The content of the .htaccess file in sub_folder:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "webdav"
AuthUserFile /var/www/test/passwd.dav
Require user test
```

`root_folder` contains the following `.htaccess`

```
Satisfy any
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from env=ALLOWED
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI "^/+webdav/root_folder/?$" ALLOWED
```

Note, please, that i am using `WebDav`.

It is set up in `/etc/apache2/conf.d/webdav`. The file contains the following:

```
Alias /webdav /home/user/projects/test/public
<Location /webdav/>
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from #list of ips here
    DAV On
    PassengerEnabled off
    LimitXMLRequestBody 0
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
</Location>
```

The problem is that when i try to access `localhost/webdav/root_folder/` folder using browser the `sub_folder` is not displayed.
But when i remove the `Require user some_user` directive the `sub_folder` is shown in the list. If i try to enter `localhost/webdav/root_folder/sub_folder/` when `Require user` directive is enabled i'm asked to enter login and password and everything is ok if i enter correct credentials.

Is it possible to list everything within directory and at the same time use `require user`  directives in .htaccess files inside sub_folders to control access to them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your root_folder (I believe that is your `$DOCUMENT_ROOT`) create .htaccess file with following content:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI "^/*$" ALLOWED

Satisfy        any
Order          deny,allow
Deny from      all
Allow from     env=ALLOWED
```

If `root_folder` is not $DOCUMENT_ROOT then use:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI "^/+root_folder/?$" ALLOWED
```

as the first line.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Well, now the `sub_folder` is shown, but when i hit it i am not asked to enter my login and password. And my goal is to control access to different directories without hiding them.

Comment: In my setup it does ask for login/password when I click on sub_folder from the list. Can you please post your both .htaccess from root_folder and sub_folder.

Comment: On my Apache installation I have tried everything but it always lists sub_folder from root_folder and asks login/password when I click on sub_folder. Only thing that I don't have is mod_dev loaded and DAV on. I will try that as well in a while and let you know.

Comment: I think `Satisfy any` directive breaks the scheme in my case because i have `Allow from #long list of ips` in `webdav` config file inside `/etc/apache2/conf.d`. This ip-list contains `127.0.0.1` so if i try to access some `sub_folder` Apache's config parser finds this directive and allows access to this `sub_folder`. In fact it will allow access if ANY condition within `Allow` directive is satisfied. Using `Satisfy all` still prevents directories from being shown. If i use `Satisfy any` and remove `Allow from #ip-list` from `webdav` file everything works as you described.

Comment: Oh I see I was suspecting DAV stuff. But great to know that you've found the root cause. I suspect if you access your web server form an IP that is not in allowed list of webdav it will behave exactly as I described.

Comment: Another problem occurs if `sub_folder` can be accessed by `user_1`. But i have some directories inside this `sub_folder`, and they should be available only for `user_2`. When i hit `sub_folder` and enter `user_1` credentials the directories inside `sub_folder` are not shown and i come to the initial situation.

Comment: May I dare say that the nature of the problem has changed totally with the addition of per user privileges. If you note that my answer was able to solve the original problem posted here. However if you want answers to this specific situation (individual user level access) then please feel free to create a new question and SO users (including me) will try to provide you a solution to that as well.